# Outlook not showing UTF-8 Encoded Text (ÛŒØ¨ Ø³Ø§Ø¦Ù¹ Ù) email by php mail

Tags: php, email, utf-8, outlook

When  i am sending UTF-8 email using mail() from my site . Gmail showing it very nice but outlook showing it like this ÛŒØ¨ Ø³Ø§Ø¦Ù¹ Ù

my code is

```
    $to = "xxx@gmail.com";
    $subject ="Subject";
    $headers  = "From: xxxx \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset:UTF-8 \r\n";
    $message  = "email message";
```

`mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add encoding to your subject

```
$subject='==?UTF-8?Q?Subject?='
```

and/or a Content-Transfer-Header

```
$headers.='Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'
```

depending on the message part the encoding problem shows.